# How web browser access content(html) from http server?

Tags: c, http, lighttpd

Currently, I'm studying [lighttpd](https://www.lighttpd.net/) which is a small web server.

I tried to figure out how server works by using `strace` first but I found something weird, following runs lighttpd by strace:

```
$ strace ./lighttpd -D -f lighttpd.conf

...

# Web browser access localhost:3000/

epoll_wait(4, [], 1025, 1000)           = 0
epoll_wait(4, [], 1025, 1000)           = 0
epoll_wait(4, [], 1025, 1000)           = 0
epoll_wait(4, [{EPOLLIN, {u32=3206347936, u64=94861854047392}}], 1025, 1000) = 1
accept4(3, {sa_family=AF_INET, sin_port=htons(40532), sin_addr=inet_addr("127.0.0.1")}, [112->16], SOCK_CLOEXEC|SOCK_NONBLOCK) = 5
getsockopt(5, SOL_TCP, TCP_NODELAY, [1], [4]) = 0
brk(0x5646bf20f000)                     = 0x5646bf20f000
read(5, 0x5646bf20c600, 8191)           = -1 EAGAIN (Resource temporarily unavailable)
epoll_ctl(4, EPOLL_CTL_ADD, 5, {EPOLLIN|EPOLLERR|EPOLLHUP|EPOLLRDHUP, {u32=3206595920, u64=94861854295376}}) = 0
accept4(3, 0x7ffcb0801b60, [112], SOCK_CLOEXEC|SOCK_NONBLOCK) = -1 EAGAIN (Resource temporarily unavailable)
epoll_wait(4, [], 1025, 1000)           = 0
epoll_wait(4, [], 1025, 1000)           = 0
epoll_wait(4, [], 1025, 1000)           = 0
epoll_wait(4, [], 1025, 1000)           = 0

# Web browser access localhost:3000/ second times

brk(0x56083a818000)                     = 0x56083a818000
stat("/.../test/", {st_mode=S_IFDIR|0775, st_size=4096, ...}) = 0
stat("/..../test/index.html", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0664, st_size=15608, ...}) = 0
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/.../test/index.html", O_RDONLY|O_NOCTTY|O_NONBLOCK|O_CLOEXEC) = 7
fstat(7, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0664, st_size=15608, ...}) = 0
fstat(1, {st_mode=S_IFCHR|0620, st_rdev=makedev(0x88, 0x4), ...}) = 0
writev(5, [{iov_base="HTTP/1.1 304 Not Modified\r\nConte"..., iov_len=217}], 1) = 217
read(5, 0x56083a7f4600, 8191)           = -1 EAGAIN (Resource temporarily unavailable)
epoll_wait(4, [], 1025, 1000)           = 0
```

Why there isn't any IO(or `send`) after requesting by web browser? If not, how browser know what content to display?

Following is buffer's content(second http response) in `writev` in above case:

```
HTTP/1.1 304 Not Modified
Content-Type: text/html
ETag: "2940132131"
Last-Modified: Mon, 08 Mar 2021 14:20:42 GMT
Content-Length: 15608
Accept-Ranges: bytes
Date: Mon, 08 Mar 2021 23:35:28 GMT
Server: lighttpd/1.4.60-devel-lighttpd-1.4.59-40-g8c7dbf1a
```

Comment: The client has the document cached. It asked the server to send the file only if it has been changed since it was cached. `304 Not Modified` means that the file hasn't changed, so the client can use its cached copy.

Comment: The buffer you show is not the same as the buffer shown by `strace`.

Comment: Thanks for notification, that must be second times to access server. I change the description of problem.

Comment: The trace is missing some details. There absolutely must be some `read()`/`recv()` calls to read in the client's HTTP request (regardless of whether a cache is used), and then `write()`/`send()` calls to send the HTTP response. That is the only way HTTP over TCP can work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Steven: Your question omits important parts of the `strace` that you did not understand, yet for some reason still chose to omit.

Before continuing to study lighttpd, you might wish to peruse the `strace` man page.

Then try this: `strace -s 4096 ./lighttpd -D -f lighttpd.conf`